# Why am I getting an invalid pointer error when I try to free malloced pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

I'm trying to learn about how arrays of strings can be created in C using malloc (i.e. dynamically sized arrays of strings).

I can get everything working but I'm getting an "invalid pointer" error when I try to free the char* pointers stored in namesArray->data[0] and namesArray->data[1]

But if I don't use free on these two pointers, I get memory leaks.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? I'm stumped

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef char* string;

typedef struct List_Repr {
    string *data;
} *list;

// add names to the supplied string array, myList
void addNames(list *myList, int numOfNames){
    //this is the equivalent of char** i.e. array of pointer to strings
    (*myList)->data = (string*)malloc(numOfNames*sizeof(string*)); //mallocing an array of char pointers
    
    //this is the equivalent of char* i.e. the strings themselves
    (*myList)->data[0] = (string)malloc(sizeof("Raymond")+1);
    (*myList)->data[0] = "Raymond";
    (*myList)->data[1] = (string)malloc(sizeof("George")+1);
    (*myList)->data[1] = "George";
}

//prints the names in the supplied array, myList
void printNames(list *myList){
    printf("%s\n", (*myList)->data[0]);
    printf("%s\n", (*myList)->data[1]);
}

int main()
{
    
    list namesArray = (list)malloc(sizeof(list)); // mallocing the namesArray

    
    addNames(&namesArray,2);
    printNames(&namesArray);
    
    free(namesArray->data[0]); //why does this free() command give me an error?
    free(namesArray->data[1]); //why does this free() command give me an error?
    free(namesArray->data);
    free(namesArray);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Advice: Don't typedef pointers. It makes the code harder to read and understand.

Comment: Techincally `malloc(numOfNames*sizeof(string*))` should be `malloc(numOfNames*sizeof(string))`. Though in this case it won't cause any problem as they happen to be the same size.

Comment: You're throwing away the `malloc`ed pointers here: `(*myList)->data[0] = "Raymond"` and here: `(*myList)->data[1] = "George"`.

Comment: `list namesArray = malloc(sizeof *list)`  or `malloc(sizeof *namesArray)`.  You've allocated only a pointer-sized buffer of storage.  Because `list` is a `typedef` for a pointer type, `sizeof(list)` is the number of bytes in a pointer, which is smaller than the list structure.

Comment: `(string)malloc(sizeof("Raymond")+1);` This should be either `malloc(strlen("Raymond")+1);` or `malloc(sizeof("Raymond"));`. The result of `sizeof` already includes the terminating 0 byte, while `strlen` does not count it. Also the return value of `malloc` and similar functions should not be casted in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(*myList)->data[0] = (string)malloc(sizeof("Raymond")+1);
(*myList)->data[0] = "Raymond";
```

The second assignment overwrites the `malloc` pointer. Which means you can't `free` the original pointer anymore as it is lost. Since you don't need to actually change the string you can just delete the first line completely and then there would be no need to `free`. Or if you want to be able to have a modifiable string then use `strcpy((*myList)->data[0], "Raymond");`

Another problem is that `malloc(numOfNames*sizeof(string*))` should be `malloc(numOfNames*sizeof(string))`. Though in this case it won't cause any problem as they happen to be the same size. But it should be fixed nevertheless.

Comment: Thank you! This has fixed the issue! I hadn't realised that I was overwriting the malloced pointer. I've since removed the malloc() commands where I create string literals and the compiler executes the code with no errors. Thank you :-)